# How to get the Description?

Tags: magento2, product, catalog

I have display description on product view page using xml
below:

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.description" template="product/view/attribute.phtml" group="detailed_info">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getDescription</argument>
        <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">description</argument>
        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">description</argument>
        <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
        <!--argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Details</argument-->
    </arguments>
</block>
```

but I want to display product listing page? how to display it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`In Store > Attributes > Product > Description > Storefront` Properties set Visible on Catalog Pages on Storefront and Used in Product Listing to `TRUE`.

In your code `list.phtml` you can use:

```
<?php echo $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output')->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getDescription(), 'description') ?>
```

or

```
<?php echo $_product->getDescription() ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using this code, you can not show description on product listing page.**

Open list.phtml Then add below code at

```
<div class="product description product-item-descriptions">
    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getDescription(), 'description') ?>
</div>
```

**before ....** `<?php if ($showDescription):?>`

*You have you checked if the attribute description is  "use in product listing" property of the attribute is set to 'yes'*

**Then Further, try reindexing if required.**